# subversion restrict access growing versions of the one file

Tags: svn, permissions, hook, restriction, pre-commit

I am trying to discover the best way to implement a write restriction on a file in subversion.

There will be, over time, many tags and branches of this file. 
One particular user, user build, must have access to this file (in all possible branches or tags) and nothing else.

```
i.e., 
svn://app/trunk/changelog.txt
svn://app/branches/1.1/changelog.txt
svn://app/tags/1.2/changelog.txt
etc..
```

As you can see, this is not a finite set of files, but one file which will be, over time, copied to various branches and tags. We can ensure, however, that the filename is unique in the file tree.

To implement this restriction, on user 'build', for all files named 'changelog.txt', 
I have thought to implement a pre-commit script.

Is this the best way ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by writing a pre-commit hook and putting it in /hooks within the repository.

Subversion will always pass the repository directory and the revision number to your hook.

Pseudobash example:

```
REPO="$1"
NO="$2"
AUTHOR=`svnlook author $REPO -t "$NO"`
FILES=`svnlook changed -t "$NO" "$REPO" | cut -b2-`


if echo $AUTHOR | grep -q builduser; then
    for FILE in $FILES; do
        if ! echo $FILE | grep -q changelog.txt$; then
            exit 1
        fi
    done
fi
```

You get the gist of it, I hope.

Comment: Note: this disallows any commit by "builduser" on anything that doesn't end in "changelog.txt".

Comment: Thanks for the answer....  I had started something like this, but was discouraged by the fact that I am getting an error...
"Repository argument required"
when attempting to call 'svnlook'. Another stackoverflow article hits that I actually need to pass this script arguments (whereas, i'd assumed subversion itself passes the arguments 'repo, txn' to this script....  Red-book doesn't seem to have much information.. (or am I looking in the wrong section?)

Comment: tim - that is exactly what I was after

Comment: Can you add "set -x" to the top of your script and show me the output?

Comment: Lambalais
`sean@svUbuntuA:~/test/working/project$ svn commit --username sean --password astraia -m "a note"
Sending        test.txt
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
+ SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
+ /usr/bin/svnlook log -t 10-o /home/sean/test/subversion/repo
+ grep [a-zA-Z0-9]
+ set -e
+ /usr/bin/svnlook author -t 10-o
Repository argument required
Type 'svnlook help' for usage.
+ AUTHOR=`
p.s. sorry for the mess.... .still trying to figure out how to set this comment as 'code'

Comment: sorry,  I believe it was a typo. I have got it partially working. Will report back when I have more to say.